# Terminology for parts of limit notation

Tags: calculus, notation, terminology, limits

When we talk about: $$\lim_{x\to{c}}f(x)=L.$$ Is there a formal name for the number "$c$"?

I know that the notation means "$L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$". It just would be nice to be able to refer to "$c$" separately without saying "what $x$ approaches". I tried to look at various textbooks but didn't find anything.

Comment: I am not aware of a standard terminology.

Comment: Just for fun: The "approachand," pronounced ah-proach-and, analogous to "operand."

Comment: I  generally refer to it as "the limiting value of $x$".  It is a little clunky, and probably not any better than "the thing which $x$ approaches", but works.

Comment: Maybe "approach value" for $c$ and "limit value" for $L$?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I believe the "correct" term based on Latin would be "appropiand" (that which is to be approached).

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan Isn't the "f(x)" called *function*?

Comment: Maybe, we could refer to $c$ as *the limit point* because, in the definition of limit, $c$ has to be a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of the domain. This expression would be good because, according to the general definition, a limit point of the domain is a point that (i) can be approximated by elements of the domain and (ii) need not be in the domain (which are the two properties of $c$ that have to be highlighted for the students).

Comment: "Center of the limit"?

Comment: I was about to suggest the same as @Pedro and wanted to add, some might get potentially confused and stumble wondering whether limit point refers to $c$ or $L$ but one thing I try to do to subconsciously reinforce a distinction is to refer to "points" in the domain and "values" in the range (as consistently as I remember, and when e.g. you compose one function into another the terminology plays not so well, but I want to think it helps).

Comment: If you are proposing an answer to the question, please consider leaving an answer, instead of a comment. Comments that are mini-answers have several issues: they cannot have their own comment threads, they dissuade others from posting answers, they cannot be voted on, and they cannot be accepted.

Comment: I've always heard the phrase "limit of $f$ at $c$", so one could refer to $c$ in this indirect way. If I find the time to locate it in the literature, I'll leave it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I vote for Pedro. We should call the point at which the limit is taken the limit point. In contrast, the value obtained by the limit (if it exists) is the limit's value. In particular, 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L $$
has limit point $c$ and the value of the limit is $L$. This terminology keeps with the usual usage of the term *value* for outputs of the function. In addition, while the term *limit point* does have a more abstract topological definition, I don't think there is much danger of confusion.

Comment: "The limit point of the limit"?

Comment: Yep. The limit point of the limiting operation.

Comment: If the co-domain is a topological space, then _point_ could also refer to a point in the _co-domain_. I think this will normally not be an issue. But if we want to disambiguate, we might call c the _limit point of the domain_.

Comment: So we get to call it a limit point AND eat chimichangas next year? Sounds good to me!

Comment: @Raciquel I am about 95% sure I've seen this usage in a standard Advanced Calculus text. But, I don't have it handy at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The "c" in limit notation is called the index (or at least that's what I have always been taught).

Comment: It would help to link to some reference which uses this term.

Answer (score -1):

Not standard but how about: the limit of $x$ or the limit of the independent variable?

Comment: Using limit of $x$ for $c$ would easily be confused with the limit's value $L$.